# Approximate integral: $\int_3^4 \frac{x}{\sqrt{(7x-10-x^2)^3}}dx.$

Tags: calculus, integration

> Approximate integral: $\int_3^4 \frac{x}{\sqrt{(7x-10-x^2)^3}}dx.$

My attempt:

Let I = $\int_3^4 \frac{x}{\sqrt{(7x-10-x^2)^3}}dx$

$u=7-x\implies I=\frac 72 \int_3^4 \frac 1{\sqrt{(7x-10-x^2)^3}}dx$ Now I have to approximate this...

I got to this point too:
$u=3-x \implies I= \int_0^1 \frac {1}{\sqrt{(-x^2-x+2)^3}}dx.$

and: $\frac 1{-x^2-x+2}\leq1\implies \int_0^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{(-x^2-x+2)^3}}dx\leq \int_0^1-\frac{1}{(x+2)(x-1)}dx$ and the right one does not converge...

I have these  values:

$a) (\frac 9{10};\frac {19}{20})$

$b) (\frac {19}{20},1)$

$c) (1;\frac {21}{20})$

$d) (\frac {21}{20};\frac {11}{10})$

$e) (\frac {11}{10},\frac {23}{20})$

$f) (\frac {23}{20}; \frac 65)$.

Comment: Some additional context is necessary to provide a useful answer. For instance, splitting this integral into a sum of smaller integrals and approximating them with a trapezoidal rule is guaranteed to work, but maybe is too much work for your context. Recognizing your first substitution yields an integral symmetric around $x=3.5$ and performing a single trapezoidal estimate on $[3, 3.5]$ (and doubling it) also yields an accurate enough heuristic to "make the correct choice". Or quadratures, series expansions, etc. could all be applied to get arbitrarily good apprixmations to the integral.

Comment: According to Wolfram Alpha the exact value of the integral is $\frac{7\sqrt{2}}{9}\approx 1.0999$, which tells us two things: (i) the answer is d) and (ii) there's probably a simple way to prove the exact result (by substitution, I expect), probably using the factorisation $7x-10-x^2=(x-2)(5-x)$.

Comment: can you not just find the exact result, the steps are not that complex

Comment: Since this value is 1.0999, this problem can't be approximated on given choices.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$ \int_{3}^{4}\frac{x}{\sqrt{(x-2)^3 (5-x)^3}}\stackrel{x\mapsto\frac{7}{2}+z}{=}\int_{-1/2}^{1/2}\frac{z+7/2}{\sqrt{\left(9/4-z^2\right)^3}}\,dz=\frac{7}{2}\int_{-1/2}^{1/2}\frac{dz}{\sqrt{(9/4-z^2)^3}} $$
since the integral of an odd integrable function over a symmetric interval (with respect to the origin) equals zero. By symmetry again, the RHS equals
$$ 7\int_{0}^{1/2}\frac{dz}{\sqrt{(9/4-z^2)^3}}=28\int_{0}^{1}\frac{du}{\sqrt{(9-u^2)^3}}=\frac{28}{9}\int_{0}^{1/3}\frac{dv}{(1-v^2)^{3/2}} $$
or 
$$ \frac{28}{9}\int_{0}^{\arcsin(1/3)}\frac{d\theta}{\cos^2\theta}=\frac{28}{9}\tan\arcsin\frac{1}{3}=\color{blue}{\frac{7}{9}\sqrt{2}}\approx 1.09994. $$
This also has a nice geometric/probabilistic interpretation, since $\frac{\mathbb{1}_{(0,1)}(x)}{2\sqrt{x}}$ is the PDF of a squared $U(0,1)$ random variable and the given integral essentially is a convolution integral.

Comment: 1.1 can't decide choices.

Comment: @TakahiroWaki: that is not true. The only option enclosing the actual value is d).

Comment: I say we don't know whether 1.1 means d or e. So you have to say that is 1.09.

Comment: @TakahiroWaki: fine, fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I will try to solve the problem.
The integrand has the form $P_1 \cdot Q_2 ^ {- 3/2} $.

It is logical to assume that the antiderivative has the form $ R_1 \cdot Q_2 ^ {- 1/2} $.

Differentiate and equate.

$\bigg((ax+b)(7x-10-x^2)^{-\frac{1}{2}}\bigg)'=x\cdot (7x-10-x^2)^{-\frac{3}{2}}$

So $\displaystyle a(7x-10-x^2)^{-\frac{1}{2}}+(ax+b)(7-2x)\cdot -\frac{1}{2}\cdot (7x-10-x^2)^{-\frac{3}{2}}=x\cdot (7x-10-x^2)^{-\frac{3}{2}}$

So $\displaystyle a(7x-10-x^2)+(ax+b)(7-2x)\cdot -\frac{1}{2}=x$

So we get $\displaystyle a=\frac{14}{9}$ and $\displaystyle b=-\frac{40}{9}$

So $\displaystyle \int^{4}_{3}\frac{x}{\sqrt{(7x-10x-x^2)^3}}dx=-\frac{1}{9}\bigg(\frac{14x-40}{\sqrt{7x-10-x^2}}\bigg)\bigg|^{4}_{3}=\frac{7\sqrt{2}}{9}.$